# What string is used to create a line break in Facebook's messenger API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I've seen in a few answers that the Graph API accepts `<center></center>` instead of `<br>` and some other parts of their API seem to accept `\r\n`.

Is there currently any way of sending a line break and if there is where it it documented?

I've looked all through their ["Getting started guide"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/quickstart) but it doesn't show up anywhere in it.

Comment: i believe line breaks are not possible anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what template and property you refer to.

Regular messages support \n, but you cannot add line breaks to other properties like for example the title of a generic template.

HTML tags aren't supported at all by the Messenger Platform, but you can of course use them in webviews.